# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} \frac{k}{(n-k)^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-sum

I am trying produce a closed form for $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ where:

$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} \frac{k}{(n-k)^2} $$

For example, if $n = 10$:

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{4} \frac{k}{(10-k)^2}  = \frac{0}{10^2}+\frac{1}{9^2}+\frac{2}{8^2}+\frac{3}{7^2}+\frac{4}{6^2} = 0.2159 $$

If $n = 1000$: $S_n = 0.3059$

If $n = 10000$: $S_n = 0.3068$

Though simulation, as $n$ increases, this series converges to $\approx 0.3069$.

However, I would like to know how to calculate this value without resorting to plugging in large $n$. Even an approximation of the summation as a function of $n$ would be fine.

However, my knowledge of sum calculation is limited to geometric series and harmonic sequences.

### What I've tried:

#### Series Analysis

I tried to find some patterns in the sequence, and know that the first term is always $0$, and the last term is always $\frac{n/2 -1}{(n/2 + 1)^2}$, which approaches $0$ as $n$ increases, but I'm not sure how to generate a closed form solution for $S_n$.

I also thought of breaking the series up into two parts as shown:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} k \cdot \frac{1}{(n-k)^2} $$

So there would be an arithmetic progression ($S_{n+1} = S_{n} + 1 $), with each term multiplied by $1/{(n-k)}^2$, but this still has lead me nowhere.

I have noticed that if the series was:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} \frac{n}{(n-k)^2} $$

($k$ in numerator replaced with $n$), the sum converges to $1$. I did this because this series is strictly larger than the original, and I wanted to use the direct comparison test to formally prove convergence. Of course, I don't know how to prove that this series converges either, so this wasn't much help.

#### Integration

The last thing I tried was to plot the values of each term in the summation, and then plot them for different $n$. If I could get an equation for these curves as a function of $n$, I should be able to integrate them and get the summation value, right? The curves look to have the general form:

$$ f(k) = y \cdot (e^{k\cdot x} - 1)  $$

where $x$ and $y$ are two real numbers. Does this idea hold merit? How could I find these curves analytically?

[image]

MATLAB code used to calculate sum:

```
n = 1000;
sn = 0;
for k = 0:n/2-1
    sn(k+1) = k / (n-k)^2;
end
sum(sn)
```

Comment: Try to use [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html) to guess an exact form when you have an approximation. This will not prove anything but may give you something to work towards. Also, you can try vectorized code to calculate for large $n$ more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting changes, and for the cool resource, that looks like a really powerful tool for finding something to aim for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the Riemann sum

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1}\frac{k}{(n-k)^2}&=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1}\frac{k/n}{(1-k/n)^2}
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1}\frac{k}{(n-k)^2}= \int_0^{1/2}\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\,dx=1-\log(2)$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer! I follow the first step with the multiplying num and dem with 1/n (which is neat for the denominator). However, I've never seen the conversion of the series to integral before. Is there a name for that so I can learn how to apply it myself?

Comment: @Michael the series is a lower Riemann sum of $\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx$ where $f(x) = x/(1-x)^2$ because you’re summing $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(a_{i}-a_{i-1})f(a_{i-1})$ where $a_i=i/n$. Look up the Riemann Sum tag on this site for more examples.